# Video.js Local Offline Video Problems

Tags: flash, offline, video.js

I am putting together an educational package that includes offline video content (i.e. loaded from local disk). When using video.js on local files the flash player component generates the following message in FF:

```
Adobe Flash Player has stopped a potentially unsafe operation. The following local application on your computer or network:

    [...]/videojs/video-js.swf

is trying to communicate with this Internet-enabled location:

    null
```

This is a common problem with playing offline videos through flash, and most players generate this error, but I know it is not necessary. For example, jwplayer version 5 does not generate this error if you edit the jwplayer.js file, [as described here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/30159/jwplayer-offline-play/). I tested and verified that to work.

Is there a way to do this with video.js?

The reason I need this is that I am working with deployment restrictions. I can't use HTML5 video in all cases, and I can't expect all users to whitelist the file. Thanks for any insight.